# Ranked responses across survey questions

Tags: survey, ordinal-data, ranking

We have a set of arthritis disease activity questions. Patients are given a scenario that describes a disease activity level scenario, like (A)"It is not painful to write" or (B)"It is painful to write" then for each of these scenarios, participants are asked to rate the arthritis activity as minimal to severe (on a 0-100 scale). Obviously example A should be less than example B. There are 4 such scenarios, along with other demographic data. We want a measure of "properly ranking" the disease activity across the 4 questions/scenarios.

We are looking for suggestions and or methods or examples to describe the proper ranking of disease activity and the demographic measures that predict the "proper ranking"
One idea we had is to use some method of calculating slope through one or more points and using this as our outcome.